# how can I show my loading icon after my ajax is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a simple javascript function like so:

```
function showHint() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            //extract data here

        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "articles.php?q=" + cat + "&year1=" + start_year + "&year2=" + end_year, true);

    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I want to be able to show my loading icon after the ajax finishes. I show my loading icon at the very beginning of my js by using:

```
$.mobile.loading("show");
```

which shows the icon nicely (using jquery mobile). However, I need to only hide the icon after the ajax is completely finished. I've attempted to use a .done() in jQuery like this but I don't think I'm using it properly:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange.done(function(){
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
});
```

Comment: Odd mix of native JS and jQuery here. If you're using jQuery for the loading spinner, you may as well use it to send your AJAX request which would be a one-liner using `$.get`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use it `onreadystatechange` callback function.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         $.mobile.loading("hide");
    }
}
```

As you are already using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). You can simply use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) like

```
$.mobile.loading("show");
$.get("articles.php?q=" + cat + "&year1=" + start_year + "&year2=" + end_year, function(data) {
    //Do something
}).done(function() {
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
});
```

Comment: yep, that did the trick. can you explain what readyState equal to 4 means? thanks!

Comment: @RDoolabh, It means `All the data has been received.` [readyState property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms534361(v=vs.85).aspx)